# Is there a way to get Apollo type guards out from a package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I see Apollo type guard I want to use in my app, it is

```
export function isField(selection) {
    return selection.kind === 'Field';
}
```

It is located at `node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/graphql/storeUtils.js`. But I cannot just import it to my file, since the lib seems not to export it and if I paste just `import { isField } from '@apollo/client/utilities/graphql/storeUtils';` I get this error:

```
/Users/vorant94/git/github/vorant94-server/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/graphql/storeUtils.js:1
import stringify from 'fast-json-stable-stringify';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vorant94/git/github/vorant94-server/dist/shared/graphql/field-name-list/field-name-list.pipe.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
```

So is there a way to use it outside of a lib?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to simply install `apollo-utilities` package...